# Cannot log in with VeraCrypt + Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, veracrypt, water-damage, rescue

So yesterday I fall glass of water and a bit of them fall on my laptop.
As I realize what I have done, monitor blink twice and I push my turn on/off button, however I have set Sleep function for this button. So the computer was going to sleep and I guess he didn't finish this process as I took power cable away.

Now after computer got dry, I would like to enter the system (Windows 10). The veracrypt password screen turn on after I turn on computer. I am inserting correct password and nothing get changed. This screen can be like half an hour without change. No wrong password communicate, not Windows logon, neither Windows booting screen appears.

What Can I do now ? I would try to burn Vera Crypt Rescue Disk, but my cd-rom reader is not running as well. I would try to burn it on usb somehow. Is that enough or should I take another approach ? The problem is because of the water or because I suddenly turn power off ? Let me know how I can get into system, or at least enter the data I had on the second partition on that disk (encrypted with system partition).

Comment: If you are unable to use the `VeraCrypt Rescue` disk then you have no options, data recovery will not be possible, since your data is encrypted.  I would like to to add your question is extremely confusing.  I can barely understand what your problem is outside of the fact, you are unable to access your Windows installation, you might want to clarify your question.

Comment: Hopefully you have another system because it is going to be difficult to perform any solution with broken hardware.  It is very unlikely you will be able to boot into Windows, considering the broken hardware due to the water damage, if all you care about is the data another system will be required to access your data.